# Cannot display all this inline!

Tags: css

```
<h4 style="display:inline; border-bottom: 1px dotted #E5E5E5; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 15px 20px 10px;"> Chismes Populares: 

<a href="http://chusmix.com/?page_id=2090" class="popular">Ver más<div style="display:inline; font-size: 9px;"> ></div></a>
</h4>
```

I added display:inline all over and I still cannot get it to show properly.
Could anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could try to make the style, display:inline !important; What is the context of this HTML?

Comment: You got an extra ">" on the third line before </div>. Typo?

Comment: Could you create the sample here -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: it appears inline to me... http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/NkftC/

Comment: I just realized something is adding <p> all over my site. There are 2 between each thing. They don't appear on the source. Thanks I'll keep the question just in case somebody knows about the <p>s

Comment: what do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine in latest Chrome, FF on Mac and IE8 on W7.

You probably have some strange styles being applied with your CSS or your parent element isn't fitting this `h4`.

If you have any dev tools you should take a look at what styles are being applied to these elements and report back to us.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you have a stray `>` character in your code.  You should replace that with `&gt;`, see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks I changed it but I still can't align everything. The 3 things appear one in each line

Comment: I just checked what you have on my own - it was showing up on the same line for me.  You probably have a style defined on your site somewhere which is conflicting.  Try using Firebug to see what's causing it to not display inline.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the widths to a percentage, like width:25%, and then use float:left and float:right on your elements.

If that doesn't work, try using span instead of div as spans are inline by default.